# WebService property Apache CXF

Tags: java, apache, web-services, wsdl, cxf

I'm using Apache CXF to work with webservices. I have a WSDL and I generated classes with wsdl2java. In the WSDL I have the following defintion

```
<xs:complexType name="consultarTramitesPorOrganismoResponse">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:consultarTramitesPorOrganismoWSResponseSalida"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

Java Class was generated right.

I have the following client:

```
public class Cliente2 {

private static final QName SERVICE_NAME = 
   new QName("http://ws.funcionario.map.es/", 
   "reaCXFWS");

public Cliente2() {
    super();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cliente2 cliente2 = new Cliente2();

    System.out.println("principio de cliente");


    URL wsdlURL=null;
    try {
        wsdlURL = new URL("file:/D:/carlota/forja38315/reaCXFWS.wsdl");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    }

    System.out.println("cliente paso 1");
    ReaCXFWS ss = new ReaCXFWS(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
    System.out.println("cliente paso 11");
     WSREACXFService port = ss.getWSREACXFServiceImplPort();
    System.out.println("Cliente paso 2 antes de llamada");

    ConsultarCategoriasPorOrganismoWSResponseSalida resp1 = port.consultarCategoriasPorOrganismo("2");

  //  ConsultarCategoriasPorOrganismoWSResponseSalida resp = port.consultarCategoriasPorOrganismo("2");
    System.out.println("Server responded with: " + resp1);

}
```

}

When I executed the client I got the following error message:

```
 Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class      es.map.funcionario.ws.ConsultarCategoriasPorOrganismoResponse do not have a property of the name return
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$DocLit.<init>(ResponseBuilder.java:500)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIMethodHandler.buildResponseBuilder(SEIMethodHandler.java:160)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.<init>(SyncMethodHandler.java:74)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:71)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:628)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:331)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:313)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:295)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:92)
at es.map.funcionario.ws.ReaCXFWS.getWSREACXFServiceImplPort(ReaCXFWS.java:61)
at clientes.Cliente2.main(Cliente2.java:40)
 Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: return is not a valid property on class es.map.funcionario.ws.ConsultarCategoriasPorOrganismoResponse
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBContextImpl.java:931)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$DocLit.<init>(ResponseBuilder.java:489)
... 10 more
  Process exited with exit code 1.
```

Could somebody help me to fix this error?

Thanks in advance

Carlota Vina

Comment: **return** is a Java keyword and should be avoided. Try to use another name and check, if it works.

Comment: In the class consultarCategoriasPorOrganismoResponse I changed _return for salida. But I get the same error. Do I have to change in another places? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post  es.map.funcionario.ws.ConsultarCategoriasPorOrganismoResponse? Maybe a missing/misspelled setter.

Comment: XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "consultarCategoriasPorOrganismoResponse", propOrder = {
    "salida"
})
public class ConsultarCategoriasPorOrganismoResponse {

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://ws.funcionario.map.es/")
        
        
    protected ConsultarCategoriasPorOrganismoWSResponseSalida salida;

   
    public ConsultarCategoriasPorOrganismoWSResponseSalida getSalida() {
        return salida;
    }

   
    public void setSalida(ConsultarCategoriasPorOrganismoWSResponseSalida value) {
        this.salida = value;
    }

}

Comment: And you are still getting exception javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: salida is not a valid property on class es.map.funcionario.ws.ConsultarCategoriasPorOrganismoResponse? Are you sure your client is using the same class file as your server?

Comment: Could be it a mistake in configuration Apache CXF. How do I have to configure Apache CXF? Thanks in advance